# How to accomplish this task using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: I have a table in this format]

- If the student have two `studentsubjectstatus` as `Merit` `studentperformance` is `Merit`.
- If the student have two `studentsubjectstatus` as  `Pass` `studentperformance` is `Pass`
- Else is a `Fail`

So i need a new column studentperformance and the output will be like this

```
studentname       studentperformance
   A                   Fail
   B                   Merit
   C                   Pass
   D                   Fail
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query as:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT studentname, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY studentname,studentsubjectstatus ORDER BY educationmarks DESC)
         AS rownum,
         studentsubjectstatus         
  FROM  @student)
 ,CTE2 AS
 (
 SELECT  studentname , MAX(rownum) AS maxrow
 FROM CTE
 GROUP BY studentname
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT T1.studentname
       ,CASE WHEN T1.rownum = 1 THEN 'Fail' ELSE
       T1.studentsubjectstatus END AS studentperformance 
 FROM CTE AS T1
 JOIN CTE2 AS T2 ON T1.studentname=T2.studentname AND T1.rownum=t2.maxrow
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    studentName AS 'Student Name'
    , CASE 
          WHEN Merit >= 2 
              THEN 'Merit'
          WHEN Pass >= 2
              THEN 'Pass'
          ELSE 'Fail'
      END AS 'Student Performance'
(SELECT
    studentName
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN StudentSubjectStatus = 'Merit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Merit'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN StudentSubjectStatus = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pass'

      -- counting how many subjects the student failed is not needed, 
      -- but for example purposes it has been added

    , COUNT(CASE WHEN StudentSubjectStatus = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fail'
FROM Students
GROUP BY studentName)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using case when aggregate like below :

```
SELECT studentname,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN studentsubjectstatus = 'Merit' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) > 1 THEN 'Merit'
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN studentsubjectstatus = 'pass' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) > 1 THEN 'pass'
         ELSE 'fail'
       END
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY studentname
```

OR

```
SELECT studentname,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN studentsubjectstatus = 'Merit' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) > 1 THEN 'Merit'
         ELSE
           CASE
             WHEN Sum(CASE
                        WHEN studentsubjectstatus = 'pass' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END) > 1 THEN 'pass'
             ELSE 'fail'
           END
       END AS studentperformance
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY studentname
```

note: `> 1` condition can be changed to `= 2` if you want to count exact 2 rows with certain `studentsubjectstatus`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always three items per student, here's the idea.

For each `studentname`:

1. Count each `studentsubjectstatus`.
2. Sort the results first in the descending order of the count, then in the alphabetical order of `studentsubjectstatus` (so that `Fail` becomes first in case of ties).
3. Get the top result.

So, something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  studentname,
  studentperformance = (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      s.studentsubjectstatus
    FROM
      dbo.yourtable AS s
    WHERE
      s.studentname = t.studentname
    GROUP BY
      s.studentsubjectstatus
    ORDER BY
      COUNT(*) DESC,
      s.studentsubjectstatus ASC
  )
FROM
  dbo.yourtable AS t
;
```

If you do not want to rely on the alphabetical order of the values in `studentsubjectstatus`, you can make sure that `Fail` comes first by replacing `s.studentsubjectstatus ASC` with something like this:

```
CASE s.studentsubjectstatus WHEN 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
```